# Alignment of collapsed menu on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to wrap my head around this issue for over an hour now and can't seem to fix.

When my nav menu collapses and I hover mouse over the **SHOP** item in menu, it moves the **SHOP** element to the left. When I mouse away, it goes back to middle position. **SHOP** should stay in line with the other two menus (NOT move left)

I have tried adjusting the dropdown-menu class as well as CSS for dropdown but still no fix.

Any push in right direction is appreciated. Thanks

HTML:

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-layout" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index">HOME</a>
          </li>             
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle"dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded"false">SHOP</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="products">Tealights</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="products">Wax-Melts<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="products">Medium Candle</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="products">Large Candle</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="products">X-Large Candle</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link" href="contact">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.narbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a,
.narbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:hover,
.narbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:focus, {
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #909090;
}
```

[What displays on screen when hover over SHOP dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDidw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position:absolute` to teh `dropdown-menu` selector. Try this code.

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```